# Randomly Switch Case

Tags: android

Hello friends I have 2 situation but I want to do it randomly. When user click button then there is 2 situation case0 or case1 randomly changes. So text's are randomly changes too...

*lastImageName and lastImageName2 are variable strings...

```
Random rand = new Random();
int newrand = rand.nextInt(1) + 1;

switch(newrand) {
case 0:
    text1.setText(lastImageName);
    text2.setText(lastImageName2);
    break;
case 1:
    text1.setText(lastImageName2);
    text2.setText(lastImageName);
    break;
}
```

But that's not working sometimes.. What's the rand. problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the +1. Just do that: `int newrand = rand.nextInt(2);`

Answer (score 1):

```
Random rand = new Random();
int a = 0;
int b = 1;
int c = random.nextBoolean() ? a : b;
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Random#nextInt(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) generates a random number between 0 inclusive and the upper bound exclusive. I.e., `nextInt(1)` will always return `0`. Instead, you should just use:

```
int newrand = rand.nextInt(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only have two cases then use

```
boolean state = rand.nextBoolean();
text1.setText(state?lastImageName:lastImageName2);
text2.setText(state?lastImageName2:lastImageName);
```

For multiple you can also use

```
Random rand = new Random();
int newrand = rand.nextInt() % count;//count = 2 for your case

switch(newrand) {
case 0:
    text1.setText(lastImageName);
    text2.setText(lastImageName2);
    break;
case 1:
    text1.setText(lastImageName2);
    text2.setText(lastImageName);
    break;
}
```